# how to make a infinute loop of a varible

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

```
for i in a:
    print(i)
```

why doesn't it do an infinite loop?
I have tried all sorts of ways but it still doesn't work
it prints out
`a
b`
can anyone help me do this?

Comment: what is `a`?, if it is not an infinite sequence, then it is never gonna be infinite

Comment: `while True:` is an infinite loop.

Comment: well a is not a infi statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create an infinite loop with `for`, you have some options:

Create your own infinite generator for example:

```
def infiniteI():
    i = 0
    while True:
        yield i
        i++
for i in infiniteI():
    ...
```

Or, you can use some [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#module-itertools), [cycle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) or [repeat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat):

```
for l in itertools.cycle("AEIOU"):
    ...

for _ in itertools.repeat(True):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This loop iterates for each element in `a`. If `a` is finite then the loop will also be finite.